# How to download a database of grades belonging to a cohort from moodle?

Tags: database, download, moodle

How can the administrator download a database of grades belonging to a cohort from moodle? The database should contain the student's name, number, course, grade, date, teacher.

Comment: Hi, you're going to need to provide a lot more information I'm afraid.  Do you want to download an actual database, or a report?  What format do you want to download it in?  Also, who should be able to download this - is it normal site admins, or is it someone in the cohort, or ... ?

Comment: I want to download a database in excel. The database should contain all the grades of for a certain period. Let's say one year. It should have the number and name of the student, the name and/or code of the course, the date of the exam, and the grade. The normal site admins should be able to download it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need the Gradebook, or grader report.

All the grades for each student in a course can be found in the course gradebook, or 'Grader report' in Settings > Course administration > Grades or from the Grades link in the nav drawer/navigation block, depending on your theme. This produces a *table* of results (not a database) which can be downloaded into Excel. Excel is not a database tool.

More information about the Gradebook (grader report) can be found here: https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Grader_report